# Почему не связывается модель JSON ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

На Action методе не происходит связка модели. Ни в каком варианте
Код Action

```
public ContentResult Message([FromBody] MessageModel form)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Db.MessagesCV.Add(new MessagesCV
                {
                    Contact = form.Contact,
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Message = form.Message,
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Name = form.Name,
                    IP = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()
                });
                Db.SaveChanges();
                return Content("Спасибо! Свяжусь с Вами в ближайшее время");
            }
            return Content("Неправильно заполнена форма связи");
        }
```

Настройки приложения

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);            
            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Web")).UseLazyLoadingProxies()/*, contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient*/);
            builder.Services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();             
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            
            var app = builder.Build();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseMiddleware<AccessLogMiddleware>();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireHost("p.site", "www.p.site", "localhost");
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "cv",
                pattern: "{controller=CV}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireHost("cv.p.site", "www.cv.p.site", "localhost");
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "admin",
                pattern: "{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireHost("admin.p.site", "www.admin.p.site", "localhost");

            app.MapRazorPages();

            app.Run();
        }
```

Модель

```
[BindProperties]
    public class MessageModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Contact { get; set; }
    }
```

JS

```
$("#sendMessageCv").on('click', function () {
        var messageModel = new Object();
        messageModel.Message = $("textarea[name='Message']").val();
        messageModel.Name = $("input[name='Name']").val();
        messageModel.Contact = $("input[name='Contact']").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'CV/Message',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(messageModel),
            //data: { Message: $("textarea[name='Message']").val(), Name: $("input[name='Name']").val(), Contact : $("input[name='Contact']").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Пробовал передавать как JSON, пробовал простую передачу данных без [FromBody] со скриптом JS

```
$("#sendMessageCv").on('click', function () {        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'CV/Message',
            type: "POST",            
            data: { Message: $("textarea[name='Message']").val(), Name: $("input[name='Name']").val(), Contact : $("input[name='Contact']").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Ничего не помогает. В DevTools вижу что данные передаются, но с моделью они не связываются

```
public ContentResult Message(string Message, string Name, string Contact)
```

В таком виде тоже ничего не приходит

Comment: Может нужно добавить аннотацию [HttpPost] над функцией public ContentResult Message([FromBody] MessageModel form)?

Comment: @Маг-притворщик Пробовал, есть ощущение что вообще Body приходит пустой

Comment: Может здесь найдёте ответ: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/model-binding.md

Comment: @Маг-притворщик Благодарю за помощь проблема была в Мидлвар

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в том что в Middleware я считывал значение Body и таким образом фрагмент считывателя был на последней позиции. Следовательно при биндинге получалось что читать нечего поэтому и биндить было нечего